# SQL syntax error in CREATE TABLE generated by IPB forum?

Tags: mysql, sql, ipb

I have a 3GB .sql backup of an IPB forum created through the SQL Backup tool in the admin panel. I'm trying to restore it as is on my local machine to a local installation of IPB but one of the `CREATE TABLE` statements is throwing a syntax error. For the life of me, I can't see what's wrong with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE core_notification_defaults (
  notification_key varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Key',
  default set('email','inline') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Default options',
  disabled set('email','inline') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Disabled options',
  editable bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1' COMMENT 'Member can edit',
  PRIMARY KEY (notification_key)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I'm restoring the backup by piping the .sql file into `mysql`. The error thrown is:

`ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 749558: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'default set('email','inline') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMEN' at line 3`

I can't see anything wrong with that line though.

I'm a bit miffed that IPB's own backup tool is producing output that can't even be read by the standard MySQL command line tools.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: `default` is a reserved word, you need to quote it with backticks to use it as a column name.

Comment: @Barmar Ah. I got confused and thought that the reserved words rules only applied to upper-case words for a bit. Makes perfect sense now., Thanks. :)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. Thanks all!